# image not displaying on my web page when hosted in lite -server local host..?

Tags: node.js, npm, browser-sync, lite-server

[when opened the index.html file normally image is displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyht5.jpg)

[when hosted on lite server the image is not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6zuw.png)

[here is the html code and all the files directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgpWf.png)

[getting get request 404 for the image file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvSRA.png)

[here is the bs-config file for the lite-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJsPx.png)

is there any solution please...!

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you remove `..` from [img src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgpWf.png), like `/src/images/...` — it should work.
Paths should be structured keeping the root of your live-server in mind.

Comment: really thanks i completely forgot about that....u svaed my day @userhooke.